# Highcharts chart.events.redraw doesn't work for chart.xAxis[0].update

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to change the xaxis step when the chart was redrawed, e.g. when it was zoomed in. I tried the javascript function for like this:

```
chart: {
  zoomType: 'xy',
  events: {
    redraw: function(){
     var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
      chart.xAxis[0].update({
        lables: {
          step: 2
        }
      })
   }
  }
}
```

But, it doesn't work. Is that a buy? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because will create infinite loop - update options and redraw them in redraw callback. Instead I advice to use `afterSetExtremes` and call update without redraw: `.update( options, false)`